# scipy, odeint and conservation of mass

Tags: python, scipy, ode

i a struggling a bit with the following system (ODE) (k`s are not constant):

```
def my_diff(y,t,k):
    f  = np.zeros(4)
    f[0] = - k[0]*y[0] - k[1]*y[0] - k[2]*y[0]**2
    f[1]= k[0]*y[0]
    f[2] = k[1]*y[0]
    f[3] = k[2]*y[0]**2
    return f
```

Three chemical reactions are taking place:

```
f[0] .. concentration of raw-material
f[1] .. concentration of product 1
f[2] .. concentration of product 2
f[3] .. concentration of product 3
```

if i solve this system everything works fine and mass is conserved. But if i run the simulation in a loop, the mass is not conserved and my error raises linearly with the cycles.

What i do (code snippet):

```
# solve the ODE
sol = integrate.odeint(my_diff,y,t,(k,))
# update initial conditions and solve again
y = [ sol.T[0][-1] + new_pulse,
      sol.T[1][-1] , sol.T[2][-1] , sol.T[3][-1]]
```

Unfortunately the total mass in the system increases. I read my code over and over again, but cannot find any mistake.  I tried to use the IDA solver and restrict the total concentration by adding an algebraic term to the system but i struggle to define consistent initial conditions.

Would you expect a large error (up to 50 % after 20 cycles) with this type of model and ode solver ? Or should i continue searching for a bug ?

Comment: Adding `new_pulse` to the first component changes the total mass, but I assume that's *not* the change that you are talking about.  Is that correct?

Comment: *"I read my code over and over again, but cannot find any mistake."*  If you showed us your code (preferably a minimal self-contained example), maybe we could find the problem (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

You say that "my error raises linearly with the cycles". And in fact you're linearly adding mass at every cycle, because you are incrementing of the same quantity `new_pulse` your `raw_material` variable at every cycle, and `raw_material` is a linear term in the total mass of your system.

I guess the error is in the dynamical equations, not in the code. More precisely, likely you have to add your `new_pulse` variable somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Well, go to sleep before you post...

I found the error. I calculated the volume increase the wrong way. The ODE system works fine. No need of a mass balance. There is no error propagation ocurring anymore.